# Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows) -for querying with id

Tags: soql, selectivity

I am getting the below error in the trigger on Update:

> Non-selective query against large object type (more than 200000 rows)
>   -for querying with id

**Query**

```
select id ,Calendar__c, (select id from Pay_Transactions__r) from Calendar_Period__c where Calendar__c =:idd1]
```

I have posted the actual query as I see no harm in doing it.
 So, Pay_Transactions__r has a lookup to Calendar_Period__c and Calendar_Period__c has a master-detail with Calendar__c
This query does not have any `!` and is querying with an `id`.
However, when I remove the child subquery, it does not occur. I have such syntax many times and wonder what could be wrong with this query here.

Any, ideas?

Comment: I've never seen this with a sub-query like that, but two things to test: 1. Does `idd1` definitely have a value and does adding 2. does adding a whereclause to the child query help? Also, is it supposed to be `where Id = `?

Comment: try to write query like this for (Fee__c : <Your_Soql_Query>){.

Comment: What does the [Query Plan Tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&type=1) tell you about the query?

Comment: Are you dealing with [Parent-Child Data Skew](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.draes.meta/draes/draes_object_relationships_parent_child_data_skew.htm)?

Comment: If you are mostly after the child records try reversing the query and checking the query plan selectivity again. E.g.
`Select ID, Master__r.Id from Child__c where Master__r.master__c = :idd1`

Comment: This is not the actual query(as you can imagine) but when I run a query tool, it is using an index as the filter is on a master-child relationship field. I also have used such queries and subqueries retrieving the child records but not from a trigger. I used it in a controller. I know workarounds but I wanted to know why I am getting this very unusual error. This is in SB and it is definetely not in a Parent-child skew. There are hardly few records under the parent.

Comment: I could work around this issue by adding a limit to the subquery :select id ,Calendar__c, (select id from Pay_Transactions__r limit 1) from TC9P_Calendar_Period__c where Calendar__c =:idd1] but I wonder why the former failed.

Comment: @MattLacey, I have hardcoded the value of idd, so it is pretty much there.

Comment: I have seen the exact same query throw this error in batch context yet the same code and criteria on the same db runs fine synchronously. Both share the same code only entry point us different. Wonder if you found another edge case

Comment: @Eric, There are hardly 500 child->child records, not quite sure why it was failing. :(. It is good if we could rootcause the behaviour so that we code more confidently. I will doubt myself when I have to write any subqueries now :(